# Converting JsValue to Model in Scala Play2

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

When I try to convert a JsValue JSON object to an object, I get the following error

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((/_id/$oid,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))))) (JsReadable.scala:20)
```

The JSON I'm passing:

```
val environmentBody = Json.parse("""{
                       "name" : "Demo Value",
                       "schedulerUrl" : "https://ops-dev.videri.com/v1/scheduler/players/%s/schedules",
                       "playersUrl" : "https://ops-dev.videri.com/v1/crm/players",
                       "token" : "68a1fab4c911206165f3e426b50468eaa66193b56eee66ec508bf9304e6c8b92"
                   }""")
```

and the conversion:

`val envObject = environmentBody.as[Environment]`

The Environment model looks like this:

```
case class Environment(id:Option[String] = None,
                       name: String,
                       schedulerUrl: String,
                       playersUrl: String,
                       token: String) extends Model{
  def getId() = id
} 

trait Model {
  def getId():Option[String]
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. As far as I can tell, this shouldn't be throwing any validation errors.

Comment: I tried inside my project (using play 2.4) and it works just fine.

Comment: @mfirry any idea what the error could be mean then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked for me. The only thing I've done is put this line:

```
implicit val reads = Json.reads[Environment]
```

Comment: No idea, actually. The identifier '/_id/$oid', referenced as missing in exception looks strange for me. Maybe the problem is caused by your formatter/reader? How do you define it?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special:  `implicit val environmentReads = Json.reads[Environment]` and
 `implicit val environmentWrites = Json.writes[Environment]`